# R ifelse with 2 dataframes

Tags: r

consider 2 dataframes:
`p1 <- data.frame(x1 = c(5,8), y1=c(3,8)); p2 <- data.frame(x1 = c(2,10), y1=c(5,3))`

I want to compare each value of p1 respectively to the value of p2 (same position), I tried:
`ifelse( p1 < p2, p2 - p1, ifelse(p1 > p2, p1 + p2, 1))`

I want have result: `data.frame(x1 = c(7,2), y1=c(2,11))`

but it seems ifelse work only on vectors and it returns a list.

do you have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert `p1` and `p2` to matrices, your original `ifelse()` works:

```
p1 <- as.matrix(p1)
p2 <- as.matrix(p2)
p3 <- as.data.frame(ifelse( p1 < p2, p2 - p1, ifelse(p1 > p2, p1 + p2, 1)))
p3
  x1 y1
1  7  2
2  2 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
(p2-p1)*(p1<p2)+(p2+p1)*(p1>p2) + 1*(p1==p2)
```

or

```
p2 + p1*((p1>p2)-(p1<p2)) + 1*(p1==p2)
```

both of which will give

```
  x1 y1
1  7  2
2  2 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt does not work because you are using `ifelse` on dataframe. You can convert your dataframe to matrix and it would work.

```
p1 <- as.matrix(p1)
p2 <- as.matrix(p2)
ifelse(p1 < p2, p2 - p1, ifelse(p1 > p2, p1 + p2, 1))

#     x1 y1
#[1,]  7  2
#[2,]  2 11
```

You can convert the above result to dataframe if needed.